# Rotate images and save rotated images

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I want to rotate a images and then save it as rotated.

Which way is the best to do that little trick?

I'm using Angular and prefer to use a directive for that. But all I found are rendering CSS for rotating the images. Not rerendering the images.

Answer (score 3):

try this.

```
<script>
var imgOriginal = 'house.png';
var canvas=document.createElement("canvas");
canvas.width = 300;
canvas.height= 300;
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.translate(canvas.width/2,canvas.height/2);
// cria imagem inicial
var image = document.createElement("img");
image.src = imgOriginal;
document.body.appendChild(image);
function drawRotated(degrees){
    // limpa canvas, rotaciona e desenha imagem no centro
    ctx.clearRect(-canvas.width,-canvas.height,canvas.width*2,canvas.height*2);
    ctx.rotate(degrees*Math.PI/180);
    ctx.drawImage(image,-image.width/2,-image.width/2);
    // cria nova imagem no html
    var img = document.createElement('img');
    img.src = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    document.body.appendChild(img);
}
image.onload = function() {
    drawRotated(90);
    drawRotated(180);
    drawRotated(270);
};
</script>
```

look, you can call the function in a button, this case my image is 'house.png'.

look one example : [HERE](http://sergiolopes.github.io/rotate-image-canvas/)